# Runtime error 9 when trying to create a chart from a different Workbooks' data

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Set wkb = Workbooks("asd.xlsx")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wks.Range("A1:B98")

End Sub
```

This is the code I've written to create a simple chart into my current workbook with data from another workbook in the same folder. Even though the relative path is the same the program returns runtime error 9, which says that I'm referencing a non-existent file. I've even tried putting the absolute path into the `wkb` variable, but doesn't work there as well.

Any help on this? TIA.

Comment: On which line does the error appear? Is the workbook "asd.xlsx" open?

Comment: `Workbooks("whatever")` applies to open workbooks. If the workbook is not open, use `Workbooks.Open("C:\ whatever complete filespec ")`. The same applies to `Worksheets("Sheet1")`, in this line `Sheet1` must exist, otherwise you get error 9.

Comment: @FaneDuru They error appears on the line `Set wkb = Workbooks("asd.xlsx")` I've even tried `Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("asd.xlsx")` to no avail.



@AcsErno, I've tried with both relative and absolute paths, both don't work. I've quadruple checked about the file name, trust me it does exist.

Comment: I asked you in my comment: "Is the workbook "asd.xlsx" open?" and you did not answer it. If it is open, this means that the workbook name is wrongly spelled. If it is not open, the error is normal. You can set only an open workbook. In such a case, you can try: `On Error Resume Next` followed by `Set wkb = Workbooks("asd.xlsx")`. Then `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` on the next row `Err.Clear: On error GoTo 0` and then `Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("Full workbook name.xlsx")` followed by `End If`.

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry if I caused any confusion. And yes the workbook is closed when I am running the script; and when I open it the script is running no issues. Thanks for the clarification. Anyway I can plot the chart without `asd.xlsx` being open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The main reason I was running in to this issue was that Excel needs the other workbook(s) to be open while plotting graphs AND the workbook in which the graph to be plotted as active. So I've modified the code to open the other workbooks, make the one in which I'm plotting the graph active, plot
the graph and then close.

`target_workbook.xlsm` is the workbook in which the graph has to be drawn, and `asd.xlsx` is workbook which contains the data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Workbooks.Open "C:\full_path_to_file\asd.xlsx"
Workbooks("target_workbook.xlsm").Activate

Set wb = Workbooks("asd.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet ABC")
Set rng = ws.Range("F3:F98,H3:H98")

MsgBox ("Test-1!")
Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=5, Width:=600, Top:=7, Height:=350)
chrt.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
chrt.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
MsgBox ("test-2")

Workbooks("asd").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the inputs, this code might be janky but gets the job done.